# IFrame's document selectors return null in DevTools Console, but then return elements after clicking Elements tab

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe, devtools

You can see my attempts at selecting elements in the screenshot below. The first two do not work, but the third attempt, which is the same as the second, works. I can't figure out if this is...

1) An expected JavaScript behavior that I'm not aware of

2) A bug in Chrome DevTools

3) Something to do with this page's DOM because of the fact it's loading as an Iframe (though I'm entering these commands after the page has loaded)

Added code:

```
<select _optionid="6AFR69NF" _optionname="Reserving with a Pass?" class="option_p" onchange="boptions_onchange(this);cb_onContentHeightChanged();">
```

[image]

Comment: Without code we can't help you, but I'm guessing it's added dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

You should check [execution context](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/#execution-context) in console. When you open DevTools it's set to "top" by default, but when you call "inspect element" inside of iFrame it changes to your iFrame automatically. You can just select necessary context from this dropdown.

[image]

[image]